# Put widgets on Canvas Tkinter

Tags: canvas, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to set a background image in my GUI, but I haven't been able to place my widgets over the canvas. I've read some similar posts and  I learnt I need to make my widgets children of the Canvas and, that's the tricky part because I've been trying, however, I can't figure it out. I have this so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 

class Layout(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master) 
        self.master= master
        self.pack()
        self.my_widget()

    def my_widget(self):

      self.C1 = Canvas(height=500, width=400)
      self.C1.place(height=1, width=3, anchor=NW)
      bgi= PhotoImage(file='bgi.png')
      self.C1.create_image(0,0,image=bgi,anchor=NW)
      self.buttonhc=tk.Button(self, height=1, width=3, bd=0.4, background='green')
      self.buttonhc["text"] = "HC"
      self.buttonhc.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=(100,2), padx=(5,5))


root=tk.Tk()
C = Canvas(root, height=500, width=400)
C.master.geometry("500x400")
C.master.maxsize(500, 400)
C.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
bgi= PhotoImage(file='bgi.png')
C.create_image(0,0,image=bgi,anchor=NW)
app = Layout(master=C)
app.mainloop()
```

I'm using a class because I'm learning OOP, but actually I think it is making this code more complex than it is. Please, help me solve this issue, I'm a bit stranded by this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing `Layout(master=root)` to `Layout(master=C)`?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work because if I do it, I won't be able to modify my layout.

Comment: I thought I could make my Layout child of two parents, but no. Something like app = Layout (master=root, c)

Comment: Use `widget.place`, not`widget.grid`

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried it and still doesn't work. I think the problem is not related to the geometry itself, It's more parent-child relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget can only be the child of a single parent/master, but there's really no difference in having a parent be the root or a canvas or any other widget.

In your specific case, you can just pass `C` as the master when calling `Layout`:

```
app = Layout(master=C)
```

Given that everything in `Layout` is a descendant of `Layout`, this will work just fine.

If you find that inconvenient, another solution is to use `place` to put the canvas on the root window, and then create all of the other widgets you want as you normally would. Using `place`, and creating the canvas before any other widgets, will allow you use `pack` or `grid` as normal in the root window and they will all appear on top of the canvas.

Comment: master = C gave me an error because I couldn't edit the geometry of my window. This was giving me a hard time and I decided to use PyQt5. Thank you so much for your time and effort! your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @duvanmendoza: tk doesn't impose any restrictions on you in this regard. There's nothing in my answer to prevent you from editing the geometry of the window. If you're having problems, perhaps you should expand your question to include additional details, since what I gave in my answer works perfectly well with the code you gave.

Comment: Yep, I finally realised how to modify the geometry of my window. I run it, but there's an empty column from the button up to the top of my window. Then I proceeded to create the canvas before my button and I still get the first result. I updated the OP so you can see how I'm doing it.

Comment: Oh, I just realised it was the padding I was using. Thank you so much!